# K is proper cone. K is pointed?

Tags: convex-optimization

In Boyd-Vandenberghe Convex Optimization and had a question about the proper cone. The following is the property of a proper cone:
• K is convex.
• K is closed.
• K is solid, which means it has a nonempty interior.
• K is pointed, which means that it contains no line (or equivalently, x ∈ K, − x ∈ K =⇒ x = 0).
A proper cone K is pointed (which means that it contains no line).
Can somebody please elaborate on what "it contains no-line" mean?
P.S. I am new here

Comment: Definitions are your friends.  Start with the definition of a cone.  Is it a subset of a Euclidean space? A vector space?  An affine space?  Context mattters.  Now "it contains no line" is an additional qualification.  What precisely a line means depends on your context, but it basically means a one-dimensional subset that extends to infinity in both directions.

Comment: Thanks. I considered the two rays that make the cone as lines. Didn't consider the negative infinity.

Comment: "(or equivalently, x ∈ K, − x ∈ K =⇒ x = 0)" sounds like you answered your own question